# Obtención de posibles cantidades de artículos - Java

Tags: java

Llevo varios días tratando con el siguiente problema, el cual solo he tenido un avance no muy bueno, el problema es el siguiente:

Estoy desarrollando un programa que me ayude a obtener el conjunto de cantidades que deban tener ciertos artículos, que al ser multiplicado por su precio y sumado el resultado de cada uno de los artículos, me de una suma total **entre 38,000 y 42,000.**

Les detallo un poco mas, suponiendo que tengo 3 artículos Ejemplo:

**Martillo**: 1,300 | **Lampara** 1,800 | **Pintura**: 900. Donde el numero del lado es el precio del articulo.

Si por ejemplo al **martillo** le ponemos una cantidad de **20** y a **lampara** una cantidad de **5** y a **Pintura** una cantidad de **5** y multiplicamos la cantidad del articulo por su precio y todos los resultados los sumamos, nos da 39,500 (Dentro del rango que quiero).

Bueno ese es el problema, y necesito que el programa lo haga por mi, pero que me saque todas las posibles cantidades que pueden tener cada grupo de artículos para que me de en el rango que quiero.

Hasta ahora he logrado muy poco, dejare por aquí el código que tengo, que la verdad no es el mejor, y esta hecho a groso modo. Aquí el código:

> EDIT: EDITE EL CÓDIGO PARA QUE SEA MAS CLARO

```
package main;

public class Ejecucion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        producto producto1 = new producto(1300);
        producto producto2 = new producto(1520);

        int i = 0;
        while(i < 10000){
             double calculo = (producto1.getPrecio()* producto1.getCantidad()) + (producto2.getPrecio()*producto2.getCantidad());
             if(calculo > 38000 && calculo < 42000){
                System.out.println("Cantidad posible "+ producto1.getCantidad()+","+producto2.getCantidad());
                System.out.println("Cantidad posible "+ producto1.getCantidad()+","+producto2.getCantidad());
                //incrementar variable de cantidad para que siga rrecorriendo las posiblidades

                producto1.setCantidad();// 
            }else{
                producto1.setCantidad();
            }

            //evaluar si da una cantidad mas grande para empezar con otro calculo
            if(producto1.getPrecio()*producto1.getCantidad() > 42000){
                //reiniciar la cantidad del producto 1 para volver a contar
                //con el nuevo indice que se le dara a producto2
                producto1.resetCantidad();
                //incrementa
                producto2.setCantidad();
            }           

            i++;
        }
    }
}

class producto{

    private int precio;
    private int cantidad;

    public producto(int precio){
        this.precio = precio;
        this.cantidad = 1;
    }

    public void setCantidad(){
        this.cantidad++;
    }

    public int getCantidad(){
        return this.cantidad;
    }

    public int getPrecio(){
        return this.precio;
    }

    //Vuelve la cantidad del objeto en 1
    public void resetCantidad(){
        this.cantidad = 1;
    }
}
```

Vale se que hay otras formas de hacer este mismo código.

Como se darán cuenta aquí solo pude lograr obtener cantidades posibles de dos artículos, y con un codigo no adecuado diria yo.
Aqui el output que me arroja al ejecutarlo:

> Cantidad posible 29,1 Cantidad posible 30,1 Cantidad posible 31,1
>   Cantidad posible 27,2 Cantidad posible 28,2 Cantidad posible 29,2
>   Cantidad posible 26,3 Cantidad posible 27,3 Cantidad posible 28,3
>   Cantidad posible 25,4 Cantidad posible 26,4 Cantidad posible 27,4
>   Cantidad posible 24,5 Cantidad posible 25,5 Cantidad posible 26,5
>   Cantidad posible 23,6 Cantidad posible 24,6 Cantidad posible 25,6
>   Cantidad posible 22,7 Cantidad posible 23,7 Cantidad posible 24,7
>   Cantidad posible 20,8 Cantidad posible 21,8 Cantidad posible 22,8
>   Cantidad posible 19,9 Cantidad posible 20,9 Cantidad posible 21,9
>   Cantidad posible 18,10 Cantidad posible 19,10 Cantidad posible 20,10
>   Cantidad posible 17,11 Cantidad posible 18,11 Cantidad posible 19,11
>   Cantidad posible 16,12 Cantidad posible 17,12 Cantidad posible 18,12
>   Cantidad posible 15,13 Cantidad posible 16,13 Cantidad posible 17,13
>   Cantidad posible 13,14 Cantidad posible 14,14 Cantidad posible 15,14
>   Cantidad posible 12,15 Cantidad posible 13,15 Cantidad posible 14,15
>   Cantidad posible 11,16 Cantidad posible 12,16 Cantidad posible 13,16
>   Cantidad posible 10,17 Cantidad posible 11,17 Cantidad posible 12,17
>   Cantidad posible 9,18 Cantidad posible 10,18 Cantidad posible 11,18
>   Cantidad posible 8,19 Cantidad posible 9,19 Cantidad posible 10,19
>   Cantidad posible 6,20 Cantidad posible 7,20 Cantidad posible 8,20
>   Cantidad posible 5,21 Cantidad posible 6,21 Cantidad posible 7,21
>   Cantidad posible 4,22 Cantidad posible 5,22 Cantidad posible 6,22
>   Cantidad posible 3,23 Cantidad posible 4,23 Cantidad posible 5,23
>   Cantidad posible 2,24 Cantidad posible 3,24 Cantidad posible 4,24
>   Cantidad posible 1,25 Cantidad posible 2,25 Cantidad posible 3,25
>   Cantidad posible 1,26

Pero el problema viene cuando tengo que evaluar 3 cantidades o mas. Y es que el numero de artículos no esta definido, pueden ser 2 o hasta 10. Así que no se darle solución.

Alguien tiene alguna idea de como darle solución? Se lo agradeciese mucho la verdad.

Un saludo!!

Comment: Revisa conceptos de backtracking.. tratar de solucionar esto con iteraciones va a ser muy dificil...

Comment: Ok, le echaré un vistazo

Comment: Como el número de artículos es indefinido, puedes optar a utilizar un `class ArrayList`y guardar en la lista, objetos de tipo `Producto`.

Answer (score 0):

He logrado reducir un poco el código...
Aún no tiene comentarios suficientes pero, es algo difícil de explicar...

```
public static class MyClass//Clase generica
{
    //constante del precio minimo en total
    private static final int MIN_PRECIO_TOTAL = 38000;

    //constante del precio maximo en total
    private static final int MAX_PRECIO_TOTAL = 42000;

    public static void main(final String[] args)//inicio del programa..
    {
        //creamos la lista de preductos
        final producto p1 = new producto("martillo", 0, 950);
        final producto p2 = new producto("pala", 0, 2460);
        final producto p3 = new producto("cierra", 0, 3300);

        //imprimimos todas las posibles cantidades.
        printCantidadesPosibles(p1, p2, p3);

        System.out.println("fin");
    }

    private static void printCantidadesPosibles(final producto...productos)//array: producto[]
    {

        int loop = 0;

        while(true)
        {

            setAllCantidad(productos, loop);
            if(getTotal(productos) > MAX_PRECIO_TOTAL)
            {
                println(productos);
                break;
            }
            for(int index = 0; index < productos.length; index++)
            {
                printWithChageIndex(index, productos);
            }

            System.out.println();

            loop++;

        }
        setAllCantidad(productos, 0);
    }

    private static void printWithChageIndex(int indexChange, producto[] productos)
    {
        float total;

        while(true)
        {
            total = getTotal(productos);
            if(acepted(total))
            {
                println(productos);
            }

            productos[indexChange].incrementCatidad();

            if(total > MAX_PRECIO_TOTAL)break;
        }
    }

    private static float getTotal(producto[] productos)
    {
        float total = 0;
        for(int i = 0;i < productos.length; i++)
        {
            total += productos[i].getPrecioTotal();
        }
        return total;
    }

    private static void setAllCantidad(producto[] catidades, int value)
    {
        for(int i = 0;i < catidades.length; i++)
        {
            catidades[i].setCatidad(value);
        }
    }

    private static boolean acepted(float precioTotal)
    {
        if(precioTotal > MIN_PRECIO_TOTAL && precioTotal < MAX_PRECIO_TOTAL)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    private static void println(producto[] productos)
    {
        for(producto p: productos)
            System.out.print("[" + p.getName() + ":" + p.getCatidad() + "]");
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static void l()
{
    System.out.println("logl");
}

//clase simple de definicion de un producto
class producto
{
    private String name;

    private int catidad;

    private float precio;

    public producto(final String name, final int catidad, final float precio)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.catidad = catidad;
        this.precio = precio;
    }

    public producto()
    {
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setCatidad(int catidad)
    {
        this.catidad = catidad;
    }

    public int getCatidad()
    {
        return catidad;
    }

    public void setPrecio(float precio)
    {
        this.precio = precio;
    }

    public float getPrecio()
    {
        return precio;
    }

    public float getPrecioTotal()
    {
        return precio * catidad;
    }

    public void incrementCatidad()
    {
        catidad++;
    }

    public void decrementCantidad()
    {
        catidad--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modificando un poco tu clase Producto para que incluya el nombre:

```java
public class Producto {
    final String nombre;
    final Integer precio;

    public Producto(String nombre, Integer precio) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.precio = precio;
    }

}
```

Y creando una clase auxiliar `Compra` que guarde los productos y la cantidad de cada uno y sobrescriba toString para imprimir los resultados más fácilmente:

```java
public class Compra {

    private final Map<Producto, Integer> items = new HashMap<>();

    public void addProducto(Producto producto, Integer cantidad) {
         items.put(producto, cantidad);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return items.keySet()
                    .stream()
                    .map(producto -> producto.nombre + ": " + items.get(producto))
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(" - "))
                    .toString();
    }
}
```

De esta forma se pueden obtener todos los casos:

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class Ejecucion {

    private static final int MIN_PRECIO_TOTAL = 38000;

    private static final int MAX_PRECIO_TOTAL = 42000;

    static final Producto martillo = new Producto("Martillo", 1300);

    static final Producto lampara  = new Producto("Lampara", 1800);

    static final Producto pintura  = new Producto("Pintura", 900);

    static final Stream<Producto> productos = Arrays.asList(martillo, lampara, pintura).stream();

    static final Map<Producto, Integer> maximos = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        // Calculo la maxima cantidad de cada producto
        productos.forEach(producto -> maximos.put(producto, (int) Math.ceil(1.0 * MAX_PRECIO_TOTAL/producto.precio)));

        // Genero todas las combinaciones posibles que esten en el rango de precios
        List<Compra> compras = generarCompras();

        // Imprimo los resultados
        compras.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    private static List<Compra> generarCompras() {
        int martillos = 0;
        int lamparas  = 0;
        int pinturas  = 0;
        List<Compra> compras = new ArrayList<>();

        while (martillos < maximos.get(martillo)) {
            while (lamparas < maximos.get(lampara)) {
                while (pinturas < maximos.get(pintura)) {
                    int total = martillos * martillo.precio + lamparas * lampara.precio + pinturas * pintura.precio;
                    if (total > MIN_PRECIO_TOTAL && total < MAX_PRECIO_TOTAL) {
                        Compra compra = new Compra();
                        compra.addProducto(martillo, martillos);
                        compra.addProducto(lampara, lamparas);
                        compra.addProducto(pintura, pinturas);
                        compras.add(compra);
                    }
                    pinturas++;
                }
                lamparas++;
                pinturas = 0;
            }
            martillos++;
            lamparas = 0;
            pinturas = 0;
        }
        return compras;
    }
}
```